# Lookup function not working

Tags: c++, class, lookup, dfa

I'm trying to have an algorithm that makes a DFA for a tic tac toe game. With the code I have right now, there are repeating states. I made a lookup function to see if the state already before adding it and add the already made state to a the parent state's vector of children.

I have tried implementing it, but I'm still getting the same number of nodes that I was getting before I implemented it meaning its never finding another state that with the same 'position' array and it is suppose to. I don't see what I'm doing wrong. It never returns anything.

UPDATE: I do know that it is returning to soon and not going through all the elements, but I don't know how to make it go through all the states and make it stop returning too soon.

UPDATE 2.0: So I've changed where my lookup is, it is now in my Main.cpp file. I also changed how it goes through, but it still isn't returning correctly.

Any ideas? Here is my code:

States.cpp

```
#include "States.hpp"

State::State(){
  final = false;
  reject = false;
  draw = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    _position[i] = 2;
  firstPlayerMove = true;
   _children = new vector<State *> ();
 };

void State::setStateChildren(State *s){
  _children->push_back(s);
}
vector<State*> *State::getChildren(){
  return _children;

}

 void State::setFirstMove(bool b){
   firstPlayerMove = b;
}

bool State::firstMove(){
   return firstPlayerMove;
}

void State::setPosition(int p[]){

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){                                                         
    _position[i] = p[i];

  }

}

int *State::position(){
   return _position;
}


bool State::isFinal(){
   return final;
}

bool State::isReject(){
  return reject;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "States.hpp"

using namespace std;

void dependents(State *root, State *state, bool first);
int size (State *s);
bool win(int p[], int symbol);                                                                         
bool draw(int p[]);


void CreateDFA(State *root, State *state, int n){
  if (n == 0 || state == nullptr)
     return;
  if (state->isFinal() || state->isReject() || state->isDraw())
    return;
  dependents(root, state, state->firstMove());
 for (vector<State*>::iterator iter = state->getChildren()->begin(); iter != state->getChildren()->end(); iter++){
    CreateDFA(root, *iter, n - 1);
  }
}

void dependents(State *root, State *state, bool first){
  int symbol;
  if (first)
     symbol = 1;
  else
     symbol = 0;
  int count = 0;
  while (count < 9){
   if (state->position()[count] == 2 && state->position()[count] != 1 && state->position()[count] != 0){                                                                        
     int check[9];
     for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
       check[i] = state->position()[i];
     check[count] = symbol;
     State *child = root->find(root, check);
     if (child == nullptr){
       child = new State();
       child->setPosition(state->position());
       child->setFirstMove(!(state->firstMove()));
       child->position()[count] = symbol;
       child->setFinal(win(child->position(), 1));
       child->setReject(win(child->position(), 0));
       child->setDraw(draw(child->position()));
     }

    state->setStateChildren(child);
     }
     count++;
   }
}

bool win(int p[], int symbol){
  if(p[0] == symbol && p[1] == symbol && p[2] == symbol)
    return true;
  if(p[0] == symbol && p[4] == symbol && p[8] == symbol)
    return true;
  if(p[0] == symbol && p[6] == symbol && p[3] == symbol)
    return true;
  if(p[1] == symbol && p[4] == symbol && p[7] == symbol)
    return true;
  if(p[2] == symbol && p[4] == symbol && p[6] == symbol)
    return true;
 if(p[2] == symbol && p[5] == symbol && p[8] == symbol)
   return true;
 if(p[3] == symbol && p[4] == symbol && p[5] == symbol)
   return true;
 if(p[6] == symbol && p[7] == symbol && p[8] == symbol)
   return true;
 return false;
}

bool draw(int p[]){
  if(p[0] != 2 && p[1] != 2 && p[2] != 2 && p[3] != 2 && p[4] != 2 && p[5] != 2 && p[6] != 2 && p[7] != 2 && p[8] != 2){
    cout << "Set Draw" << endl;
    return true;
  }
  return false;

}

int size (State *s){
  if (s == nullptr)
    return 0;
  int count = 0;
  for(vector<State*>::iterator iter = s->getChildren()->begin(); iter != s->getChildren()->end(); iter++)
    count = size(*iter) + count;
  return count + 1;
 }

bool check(int p[], int a[]){
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    if (p[i] != a[i])
      return false;
  return true;
}


State *find(State * root, int p[]){
  if (root->isFinal() || root->isReject() || root->isDraw())
    return nullptr;
  State * s = nullptr;
  for (vector<State*>::iterator iter = root->getChildren()->begin(); iter != root->getChildren()->end(); iter++){
    if(check((*iter)->position(), p)){
      s = new State (**iter);
      break;
    }
    else
      s = find((*iter), p);
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  -- please post a *minimal* example.   The less code you post that reproduces your error, the more likely people are to take the time to look for your problem.  By taking chunks out, often times you will inadvertently make the problem go away and know where to look for your problem, as well.  Or if you don't, when you've taken out everything you can you know exactly which code to be looking at.

Comment: In function `State::find(...)` the for loop is wrong, it returns `return find((*iter), p);` after the first iteration. The compiler should notify you of that if you increase the warning level.

Comment: Is this more minimal? I tried taking out everything that isn't connected to my problem, but I'm not entirely sure if the find is the problem.

Comment: Barmak, I think you nailed it. Post an answer.

Comment: What should the loop be then?

Comment: Because I did figure out that it wasn't going through the whole dfa, but I don't know how to make it loop through and then return.